# Styled-Components how to minify css in SSR?

Tags: styled-components

Using styled-components in React project with SSR. When the page loads more than half of the page weight consuming by styled components. Is there any way to improve this? Is it possible to minify generated styles ?

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    'babel-plugin-styled-components',
    {
      ssr: true,
      displayName: false,
      fileName: false,
    }
  ]
```

You can pass this in your .babelrc config.
Good documentation here - https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#minification

Although I am searching for a way to custom minify my classes. Anybody with any leads on that, please let me know.